# How to Give Default value to a LookUp field in salesforce

Tags: lookup

I am having 1 lookup field country.
i want to set it with some default value on UI.
How should i implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best solution is to use trigger. Create a insert trigger and set default value through that trigger.

Another solution is to pass the default value in the url. You have to get the id of that field and a URL can be created to set default value.

For eg. if the id of that field is 'country' , then url would be:
https://ap1.salesforce.com/003/e?retURL=%2F003%2Fo&country=USA.

A new button can be created and URL on this button can be set to this one.

Comment: Hi thanks.one more thing i need to do is to replace lookup with picklist.Plz suggest.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: i have one custom lookup field now i need to show it in the form of picklist in visualforce page.

Comment: For this , you have to create a Select List on vf page and options of that select list will be the all results of that look-up field. Then you have to use the selected value from drop-down manually and then you can use that field as you want.