# How to Give Default value to a LookUp field using Formula Editor

Tags: formula, lookup, action

I have an action on which i have one Lookup Field "Year".Year is an object with only two records - 2015 , 2016.

I have this value to be predefined as 2016 when user clicks an action
While creating a predefined value for this lookup , i tried putting directly 2016 just to check what happens as i am not aware how formula works.
i got this EXPECTED error:

> Formula result is data type (Number), incompatible with expected data
>   type (Lookup(Sales Year)

Does anyone has any idea how i can acheive this/or i can i pass the id of record 2016 in the formula editor??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try using url parameters? You may need to override the standard New button with custom button and pass the default values as url paraneters.

Comment: I am creating an standard action on Object.I dont think i can override

Comment: Can the lookup field just be adjusted to a picklist?  You could use global picklists to ensure the same set of years across all places that you reference it

Answer (score -1):

Please Refer to these documents-

[How to Give Default value to a LookUp field in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/how-to-give-default-value-to-a-lookup-field-in-salesforce)

http://www.datixinc.com/define-default-value-lookup-field-salesforce-com/

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That is URL Hacking and that we cant do in actions.We need to write the formula only to set predefined values and i guess it cant be achieve just with the formula.I think i need to create a hidden look up and using URL hack auto populate its value and then i can use it in formula in my action